# How do I fade out any specific element that is clicked on using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a jQuery function to fade out any specific element that the user clicks on within the webpage.

I have tried using the universal selector to target all the elements, but then when I click an element every single element on the page fades away. Im trying to fade away only the clicked element and the rest of the page stays.

I was thinking of adding and event listener to all elements of the page and then removing the parent node of the clicked element?

Here is my code so far:

```
$("*").click(function () {
  $("*").fadeOut(3000);
});
```

So yeah that's the function I've created already.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Ikigai</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="restaurant.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="restaurant.css" />
    <style>
      @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@100&display=swap");
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img
      class="background"
      class="fade"
      src="restaurant.jpg"
      style="display: none"
    />
    <h1 class="heading" class="fade">Ikigai</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="story" class="fade">Our Story</h1>
      <p class="story-p" class="fade">TEST</p>
      <img
        class="storyPic"
        class="fade"
        src="/pexels-kaboompics-com-6267.jpg"
      />
      <h1 class="food" class="fade">Our Food</h1>
      <p class="food-p" class="fade">TEST</p>
      <img class="foodPic" class="fade" src="/pexels-huy-phan-1409050.jpg" />
      <h1 class="people" class="fade">Our People</h1>
      <p class="people-p" class="fade">TEST</p>
      <img class="peoplePic" class="fade" src="/pexels-cottonbro-4253300.jpg" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Above  is the html Im looking to manipulate!

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: did my answer helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to target the element clicked. Because the click event propagates which results in the event handler for each element being executed.
[Event Propagation](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/javascript-tutorial/javascript-event-propagation.php)

So to achieve what you want you will have to stop the event from propagating.
Below is a working sample of this.

```js
// thi statement attaches a click event hadler with every element
$("*").click(function($event) {
  // below statement stops the event from propagation
  $event.stopPropagation();
  // below statement fades the clicked element out
  $(this).fadeOut(3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div> first div</div>
<div> second div</div>
<div> third div</div>
<div> fourth div</div>
```

Comment: Still not working sadly.. Only fades away the entire page..

Comment: ` $(this).fadeOut(3000);` is very important. Are you sure you have it with `this`, because in your question you have a `*` instead of `this` . `*` will fadeout every element as it targets all elements.

Comment: $(this).on("click", function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).fadeOut(1000);
});

This is how my function is written right now, but it does nothing when i click on any element. Nothing fades out unfortunately even with the $(this) statement.

Comment: @JordanBendon in my code if you see i have different code, try using that. Or change your code to `$('*').on("click", function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); $(this).fadeOut(1000); });`

Comment: Im afraid this code also fades out the whole page.. So confused as to why...

Comment: It seems like the $(this) statement isn't having an effect?

Comment: @JordanBendon look out the code again, i have added comments which help you understand what each lines does.

Comment: @JordanBendon also you can see this snipped can be executed here with that `Run code snippet` button and you can see it works.

Comment: Thank you I see that. However, $(this).fadeOut(3000); is not targeting a specific element to fade out, its fading out the entire page. Maybe the it is still propogating?

Comment: @JordanBendon in that case i would like to have a look at your code better. Can you add your minimal code here https://jsfiddle.net/3g4rx0hp/

Comment: Ah yes okay sorry I see that it works on Run Code Snippet. Then I think the issue is applying it to my particular html code.

Comment: I'll try apply it to my html! I'll also update the question with HTML! Thanks :)

Comment: Cool. Hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: I just edited the html in.. Maybe you can understand why it fades everything instead of specific elements :)

Comment: Do this the `jQuery` code from the snippet in this answer make sure it starts on the first line of your `restaurant.js` file and if your are using `$(document).ready` then first line inside that.

Comment: There is one more problem is see wit your `HTML` code. You have the `class` attribute twice. Instead it should be just one with as many classes you want e.x. `class="food fade class3 class4"`

Comment: Okay thanks Ill try that!

Comment: I got it to work with your advice! It was to do where I was injecting that jquery library and putting the javscript script tag at the bottom of the body!

Comment: @JordanBendon glad could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can change a few things to make your code work

- Use `.on()` to bind click function to all elements ([Difference between .on('click') vs .click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)) Not mandatory but a good practice
- use `$(this)` to target clicked element
- Use `e.stopPropagation();` to prevent event  bubbling

---

**Working code below**

(Click on any item) [if you click on page area, the whole page would fade, so try to click on elements to see the effect)

```js
$("*").on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>I am a Div</div>
<ul>
  <li> list 1 </li>
  <li> list 1 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Jordan Bendon did the answer helped?

Comment: Hey Tushar yes this was also the solution I used, thanks so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this)` to refer to the item that was clicked, so it could become:

```
 $(this).parent().fadeOut(3000)
```

Comment: $("*").click(function () {
  $(this).parent().fadeOut(3000);
});

I've tried it like this, but there is no response. Is that the way you meant it?